# Hadoop ApplicationClassLoader can't find class

Tags: hadoop, classloader, classnotfoundexception

I have a MapReduce job I'm trying to run on a GCP Dataproc cluster:

```
gcloud dataproc jobs submit hadoop \
    --cluster="$cluster" \
    --jar foo.jar \
    --properties=mapreduce.job.classloader=true \
    ....
```

When I run my job, I get this error:

```
Error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.w3c.dom.ElementTraversal
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ApplicationClassLoader.loadClass(ApplicationClassLoader.java:189)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ApplicationClassLoader.loadClass(ApplicationClassLoader.java:157)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:756)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:468)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ApplicationClassLoader.loadClass(ApplicationClassLoader.java:176)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ApplicationClassLoader.loadClass(ApplicationClassLoader.java:157)
    <xerces code>
    <my mapper code>
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.DelegatingMapper.run(DelegatingMapper.java:55)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:798)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:346)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:174)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1762)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:168)
```

The jar was created by the Maven shade plugin, and that class is in it:

```
jar -tf foo.jar | grep ElementTraversal
org/w3c/dom/ElementTraversal.class
```

Some googling suggests including xml-apis v1.4.01 as a dependency, and I have, but it doesn't make a difference, and it was already a transitive dependency. From what I read, the `mapreduce.job.classloader=true` property tells Hadoop to prefer classes in the my job's jar, not the Hadoop distribution, and this seems to be the whole point of `ApplicationClassLoader`.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that Hadoop defers to the system classloader for system classes. Modern Java ships with xml-apis (but an older version), so it was marked as a system class.

I found the `mapreduce.job.classloader.system.classes` flag that's paired with `mapreduce.job.classloader`:

> Used to override the default definition of the system classes for the job classloader. The system classes are a comma-separated list of patterns that indicate whether to load a class from the system classpath, instead from the user-supplied JARs, when mapreduce.job.classloader is enabled.

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.1/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/mapred-default.xml

Adding this to my properties fixed the issue. It excludes `org.w3c.dom` classes from what hadoop considers system classes and loads them from my job jar.

```
mapreduce.job.classloader.system.classes=-org.w3c.dom.
```